Carousel card effect using Keen-slider
I want to create a carousel card effect using Keen slider and I spent some time trying everything on the docs page but I failed so I thought I would seek help from people who might have come across this or more knowledgeable about the library.
The effect I want to achieve is growing middle item and shrinking others as I move the slider. the card in the middle appear above the others. As I move the slider to the left, the item on the right starts to grow. It becomes bigger than the current middle item until it reaches full size and becomes the new middle item.
I created an example where the middle item becomes bigger, but I am missing the effect of items growing and shrinking as the slider moves:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/carousel-card-effect-lfxsss?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx
hope someone can help me and thank you.
